# Reload panel dynamically in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am new in ext. I have a dashboard containing multiple panels each panel contains a separate display in it. I want to reload/refresh a panel dynamically. It supposed to refresh with latest/updated data from database itself.

I have tried below codes but nothing working for me. TIA.

```
Ext.getCmp('panelId').store.reload(); // it changes grid with dynamic store but not refreshing plugins in panel.
Ext.getCmp('panelId').updateLayout();
Ext.getCmp('panelId').getView().refresh();
```

Comment: Can you attach the code of `panelId` component?

Comment: What kind of plugins do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try doLayout. 
`Ext.getCmp('panelId').doLayout()`, should do a 'update layout' that you had in try two.